# how to get single popup info windows when click boxdiv

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function clicked(Object){ //getting new object data when refreshing map
    var marker=getMarkers(Object,map);//get the marker
    var infowindow=gwtInfowindow(Object);// get the info window popup

    if(currentList[Object.id].infowindow==undefined){ 
       //getting if undefined popup
       currentList[Object.id].infowindow= infowindow;
       currentList[Object.id].infowindow.open(map,marker);
    }
    else{
       infowindow=currentList[Object.id].infowindow;
       currentList[Object.id].infowindow.open(map,marker); 
       //getting info window when map refreshed
    }
}
```

- in my code when I click on map box I get current list of `infowindow`.
- but when map refreshed if object data changed then `infowindow` opened with old data(i.e. in **else case  infowindow** assigned old data of **`currentList[Object.id].infowindow`**).
- please any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- try this

  ```
  else{
  currentList[Object.id].infowindow.close();
  infowindow=currentList[Object.id].infowindow;
  currentList[Object.id].infowindow.open(map,marker); 
  //getting info window when map refreshed 
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var infowindow = null;    
function clicked(Object){
      if(infowindow !=null){
        //close infowindow
        infowindow.close();
      }
      var marker=getMarkers(Object,map);//get the marker
      infowindow=gwtInfowindow(Object);// get the info window popup
      if(currentList[Object.id].infowindow==undefined){ //getting if undefined popup
         currentList[Object.id].infowindow= infowindow;
         currentList[Object.id].infowindow.open(map,marker);
       }else{
          infowindow=currentList[Object.id].infowindow;
          currentList[Object.id].infowindow.open(map,marker); //getting info window when map refreshed
         }

}
```

Comment: I get only data wrong. but I did not multiple popups.

Comment: if I modified my code in else case   **currentList[Object.id].infowindow= infowindow;** then I get multiple popups with correct data.

Comment: Create only one instance of infowindow. And close it before opening another